# how to set JVM setting in Jboss EAP 6.4 for BRMS

Tags: java, jboss-eap-6, redhat-brms

I have installed the deployable version of  JBoss BRMS 6.4.
My linux virtual machine has 09 Gb of Memory. 
To control the JVM memory, I adapt standalone-secure.conf file by modifying the JAVA_OPTS line:

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6G -Xmx6G -XX:MaxPermSize=3g -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

I restart BRMS service, but while executing BRMS rules, top command shows java is still consuming more than 6 Gigabit of Memory.

How can I solve the issue, or what is the best way for controling Java Memory in JBoss EAP ?

Thank you for your help community

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx parameter controls the maximum size of the Java heap, but its not the only memory which allocates to java process. In addition to Xmx, PermGen, native C++ heap which is used by the JVM internals, space for the thread stacks ideallu its 1mb per thread by default on a 64 bit JVM. So total memory consued by java process is

`JvmProcessMemory = JvmHeap + PermGen + (ThreadStackSize* Number-of-Threads) + Jvm-native-c++-heap`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I will upgrade my memory to 16 Go, and see if they are improvment.
Regards